# how to set this table in IEEE paper

Tags: tables, ieeetran

[image]

```
\begin{table}[h]

 \begin{center}

   \caption{ Comparison of Maximum Accuracy of Different Methods on BCI comp III dataset IIIa
}\label{tab:2}

   \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
     \hline
     % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
     $Feature Extraction^a$ & $Classiﬁer^b$ & & Accuracy(\%)  &  &  \\ 
     \hline
      &  & K3  & K6  & L1  & $mean^c$ \\
     AAR & MDA[9] & 66.6 & 38.5 & 49.5 & 51.5 \\
     CAR+CSP & NN[10] & 81.7 & 76.7 & 73.3 & 77.2 \\
     Barlow method & SVM[11] & 63.3 & 45.0 & 60.0 & 56.1 \\
       WPD & ME[12] & 90.4 & 66.0 & 79.6 & 78.7\\
      WPD+CSP & SVM+NN[13] & 83.1 & 84.4 & 85.6 & 84.4 \\
     PLV  & SVM+Quicksort[14] & 86.0 & 82.0 & 77.0 & 81.7 \\
     Sparse PCA+Sparse CSP & SVM[15] & 85.1 & 81.6 & 80.1 & 82.3 \\
     STFT+CSP & SVM[16] & 71.3 & 88.1 & 71.2 & 76.9\\
     \hline
      4 band CSP (our method)& SVM & 93.3 & 77.5 & 85.8 & 85.5\\

     \hline 

   \end{tabular}

 \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Your table doesn't fit... what are the options? We have an FAQ for that: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5764)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your table has a number of serious issues. The fact that it is wider than `\columnwidth` is just the most serious one.

1. To make the table fit inside the text block, it suffices to (a) set the parameter `\tabcolsep` to `0pt` and (b) switch from a `tabular` to a `tabular*` environment. Armed with the `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` directive, the `tabular*` environment will reduce the intercolumn whitespace as much as is needed to make the table fit.

   If the table were any wider, one would also have to introduce line breaks in some of the cells in the two text columns. However, that doesn't seem to be necessary here.
2. The table's layout is -- pardon my bluntness -- quite unattractive. I suggest you (a) load the `booktabs` package, (b) use its line-drawing macros instead of `\hline`, and (c) provide more deliberate structure to the header material. For instance, to center the string "Accuracy (\%)" above the four data columns, encase it in a `multicolumn{4}{c}{...}` directive.
3. It looks like you're trying to create some in-table footnote markers. Whatever else you do, *don't abuse TeX's math mode* in this way. I suggest you (a) load the `threeparttable` package, (b) use `\tnote` directives to place the footnote markers, and (c) use a `tablenotes` environment after `\end{tabular*` to place the corresponding footnote material.
4. In one of the header cells, replace the odd-looking `ﬁ` with `fi`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs,ragged2e}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\TPTtagStyle{\textit}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Comparison of Maximum Accuracy of Different 
        Methods on BCI comp III dataset IIIa}
\label{tab:2}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out intercolumn spacing

\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll cccc}
\toprule
     Feature Extraction\tnote{a} & Classifier\tnote{b} & 
     \multicolumn{4}{c}{Accuracy (\%)} \\ 
\cmidrule{3-6}
     & & K3 & K6 & L1 & mean\tnote{c} \\
\midrule
     AAR & MDA [9] & 66.6 & 38.5 & 49.5 & 51.5 \\
     CAR+CSP & NN [10] & 81.7 & 76.7 & 73.3 & 77.2 \\
     Barlow method & SVM [11] & 63.3 & 45.0 & 60.0 & 56.1 \\
     WPD & ME [12] & 90.4 & 66.0 & 79.6 & 78.7\\
\addlinespace
     WPD+CSP & SVM+NN [13] & 83.1 & 84.4 & 85.6 & 84.4 \\
     PLV  & SVM+Quicksort [14] & 86.0 & 82.0 & 77.0 & 81.7 \\
     Sparse PCA+Sparse CSP & SVM [15] & 85.1 & 81.6 & 80.1 & 82.3 \\
     STFT+CSP & SVM [16] & 71.3 & 88.1 & 71.2 & 76.9\\
\addlinespace
      4 band CSP (our method)& SVM & 93.3 & 77.5 & 85.8 & 85.5\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\smallskip
\scriptsize
\begin{tablenotes}
\RaggedRight
\item[a] AAR: Adaptive Autoregressive; 
         CAR: Common Average Reference; 
         CSP: Common Spatial Pattern;
         WPD: Wavelet Packet Decomposition;
         \dots
\item[b] \dots
\item[c] \dots
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```