# Table in the appendix is not placed on the top of a page

Tags: tables, floats, align, ieeetran

I have a long table which extends over two pages in the appendix below . 
The table is not placed on the top of these pages. 
Is it normal to leave it like this? 
How can I put it on the top of a page? Please suggest if you see something wrong about this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}                      
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption} 


\begin{document}
\lipsum
\appendix
    \begin{table*}[b]
\caption{Table with images}
  \label{tab:image}
    \adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colsep=3pt,
             colspec= {c *{3}{X[c,m]} },
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             rowsep = 3pt,
             }
No  &   C1  &   C3  &   C4  \\
1   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
2   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
3   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
4  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table*}
    \begin{table*}[t]
    \ContinuedFloat
\caption{Table with images}
  \label{tab:image}
    \adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colsep=3pt,
             colspec= {c *{3}{X[c,m]} },
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             rowsep = 3pt,
             }
No  &   C1  &   C3  &   C4  \\
5   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
6   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
7   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
8   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't those two tables be one? You could try to use `longtblr` which would span one big table over two+ pages. You would get top aligned (sub)tables on the first and subsequent pages.

Comment: Actually, the design of the `IEEEtran` class is to vertically center the floats on their pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is actually an extension of my comment, in which I merged two tables in one

| Page 1 | Page 2 | Page 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\DefTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}{\scshape \InsertTblrText{caption}}
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{\scshape Continued on next page}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{
  \centering
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}\par
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}\par
}
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{
  \centering
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}\par
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}\par
}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{({\scshape Continued})}


\begin{document}
\lipsum

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Example}\label{tab:example}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
    Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
    \hline
    X & Y & Z \\
    X & Y & Z \\
    X & Y & Z \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\appendix
\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}

\onecolumn
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Table with images},
  label = {tab:image},
]{
  hlines, vlines,
  colsep=3pt,
  colspec= {c *{3}{X[c,m]} },
  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
  rowsep = 3pt,
  rowhead = 1,
}

  No &   C1  &   C3  &   C4  \\
  1  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  2  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  3  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  4  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  5  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  6  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  7  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  8  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

---

Update.
In case a long table is not an option, here's another solution with a regular table

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}
\lipsum
\appendix
\begin{table*}
  \begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{\linewidth}
    \ContinuedFloat
    \caption{Table with images}
    \label{tab:image}
    \adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
      colsep=3pt,
      colspec= {c *{3}{X[c,m]} },
      row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
      rowsep = 3pt,
    }
      No  &   C1  &   C3  &   C4  \\
      5   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
      & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
      & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
      6   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
      & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
      & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
      7   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
      & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
      & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
      8   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
      & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
      & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
    \end{tblr}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, I added `\twocolumn` at the end of the table to move it back to two columns for reference. Just one question, how can I use default table style of IEEEtran like `TABLE X` `TABLE WITH IMAGES`?

Comment: @emnha The tag (or lable) is already in uppercase format (`TABLE`). As to the caption text, if you add the following to a preamble, all caption texts will be in uppercase font, including `longtblr`: `\DefTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}{\MakeUppercase{\InsertTblrText{caption}}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{upper}{#1#2\MakeUppercase{#3}\par}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=3pt, position=top, format=upper}`

Comment: @emnha ... and the following changes a comment added to headings on subsequent pages in `longtblr`: `\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{(CONTINUED)}`.

Comment: Should I put in in any enviroment? I got the error below. Also the IEEEtran caption has TABLE in one line and the  caption is in upper font in another line without the colon.  Is there a fix for this? `"You can't use `macro parameter character # in horizontal mode.
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
unclosed group {"`

Comment: This is an example of the IEEEtran caption. 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475282/how-to-set-this-table-in-ieee-paper

Comment: I just made a picture to show the problem below. 
https://ibb.co/L9dyWMv

Comment: @emnha I updated the answer. I did not realise `caption` would completely re-format a caption style to its own default. I think now everything should fit the IEEtran style.

Comment: Looks great, thanks. I'll check it when I got home.