# Place the bibliography right below the appendix

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, appendix

I want to put the bibliography right below the appendix as follows but it doesn't work. 
  The long table is the appendix.
How can I fix this? 
Is it normal to do it like this or should I put the bibliography in a new page?

[image]

The code is long but it is mostly just the long table for the appendix. The relevant part is this:

[image]

**EDIT:**
Can this be done without using `multicol`? I read some bad news about this package in IEEEtran [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2150037) so I'm worry about using it.

Comment in the other thread:

> BibTeX doesn't seem to have a problem with it, but IEEEtran certainly
> does. Evidently, IEEEtran is doing more than just putting stuff in two
> columns when you use the two-column format, so I can't just use
> multicol. Thanks for the suggestion

Full code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}

\DefTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}{\scshape \InsertTblrText{caption}}
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{\scshape Continued on next page}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{
  \centering
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}\par
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}\par
}
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{
  \centering
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}\par
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}\par
}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{({\scshape Continued})}

\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
@article{Junginger:10, 
author = {F. Junginger and A. Sell and O. Schubert and B. Mayer and D. Brida and M. Marangoni and G. Cerullo and A. Leitenstorfer and R. Huber}, 
journal = {Optics Letters}, 
number = {15}, 
pages = {2645--2647}, 
publisher = {OSA},
title = {Single-cycle multiterahertz transients with peak fields above 10 {MV}/cm}, 
volume = {35}, 
month = {Aug},
year = {2010},
url = {http://ol.osa.org/abstract.cfm?URI=ol-35-15-2645},
doi = {10.1364/OL.35.002645},
}
@article{LPOR:LPOR201000013,
author = {Cerullo, G. and Baltu{\v s}ka, A. and M{\"u}cke, O.D. and Vozzi, C.},
title = {Few-optical-cycle light pulses with passive carrier-envelope phase stabilization},
journal = {Laser \& Photonics Reviews},
volume = {5},
number = {3},
publisher = {WILEY-VCH Verlag},
issn = {1863-8899},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/lpor.201000013},
doi = {10.1002/lpor.201000013},
pages = {323--351},
year = {2011},
}
@inproceedings{Kanuparthy:2011:SED:2068816.2068860,
 author = {Partha Kanuparthy and Constantine Dovrolis},
 title = {ShaperProbe: end-to-end detection of ISP traffic shaping using active methods},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2011 ACM SIGCOMM conference on Internet measurement conference},
 series = {IMC '11},
 year = {2011},
 isbn = {978-1-4503-1013-0},
 location = {Berlin, Germany},
 pages = {473--482},
 numpages = {10},
 url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2068816.2068860},
 doi = {10.1145/2068816.2068860},
 acmid = {2068860},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
 keywords = {active probing, inference, traffic shaping},
}  
@inproceedings{soule2004flow,
  title={Flow classification by histograms: or how to go on safari in the internet},
  author={Augustin Soule and Kav{\'e} Salamatia and Nina Taft and Richard Emilion and Konstantina Papagiannaki},
  booktitle={ACM SIGMETRICS Performance Evaluation Review},
  volume={32},
  number={1},
  pages={49--60},
  year={2004},
  organization={ACM}
}
@book{texbook,
  author = {Donald E. Knuth},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The {\TeX} Book},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional}
}

@book{latex:companion,
  author = {Frank Mittelbach and Michel Gossens
            and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle
            and Chris Rowley},
  year = {2004},
  title = {The {\LaTeX} Companion},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional},
  edition = {2}
}

@book{latex2e,
  author = {Leslie Lamport},
  year = {1994},
  title = {{\LaTeX}: a Document Preparation System},
  publisher = {Addison Wesley},
  address = {Massachusetts},
  edition = {2}
}

@article{knuth:1984,
  title={Literate Programming},
  author={Donald E. Knuth},
  journal={The Computer Journal},
  volume={27},
  number={2},
  pages={97--111},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}

@inproceedings{lesk:1977,
  title={Computer Typesetting of Technical Journals on {UNIX}},
  author={Michael Lesk and Brian Kernighan},
  booktitle={Proceedings of American Federation of
             Information Processing Societies: 1977
             National Computer Conference},
  pages={879--888},
  year={1977},
  address={Dallas, Texas}
}
@article{Khoe:1994:CML:2288694.2294265,
    author = {Khoe, G. -D.},
    title = {Coherent multicarrier lightwave technology for flexible capacity networks},
    journal = {Comm. Mag.},
    issue_date = {March 1994},
    volume = {32},
    number = {3},
    month = mar,
    year = {1994},
    issn = {0163-6804},
    pages = {22--33},
    numpages = {12},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/35.267438},
    doi = {10.1109/35.267438},
    acmid = {2294265},
    publisher = {IEEE Press},
    address = {Piscataway, NJ, USA},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\lipsum

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Example}\label{tab:example}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
    Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
    \hline
    X & Y & Z \\
    X & Y & Z \\
    X & Y & Z \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\appendix
\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}
\onecolumn
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Table with images},
  label = {tab:image},
]{
  hlines, vlines,
  colsep=3pt,
  colspec= {c *{3}{X[c,m]} },
  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
  rowsep = 3pt,
  rowhead = 1,
}

  No &   C1  &   C3  &   C4  \\
  1  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  2  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  3  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  4  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  5  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  6  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  7  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  8  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
\end{longtblr}
%
%
\twocolumn
\section{reference}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,jobname.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` start a new page. As [@ylpjört](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656440/31283) mentioned, you'd need to use `multicols` ([multicol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package) without issuing `\twocolumn`. Also add the following line before the bibliography: `\IEEEtriggercmd{\columnbreak}\IEEEtriggeratref{n}`; `n` is a reference to be moved to the next column. BTW, since you use `IEEEtran` document class, have a look at [How to Use the IEEEtran LaTeX Class](https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) by Michael Shell.

Comment: @Celdor would it be possible to wrap `\begin{table*} around `longtblr` so we don't need to use `\onecolumn`?

Comment: No it would not be possible, AFAIK. It will just turn a long table table into a regular box and exceeding part will be hidden behind a bottom edge. I am afraid you would have to get back using regular tables and split the content, accordingly. I post an answer.

Comment: I also updated another [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656349/31283) should you search for a solution on your previous problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by using the `multicol` package and use it instead of the `\twocolumn` command:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\DefTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}{\scshape \InsertTblrText{caption}}
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{\scshape Continued on next page}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{
  \centering
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}\par
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}\par
}
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{
  \centering
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}\par
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}\par
}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{({\scshape Continued})}

\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
@article{Junginger:10, 
author = {F. Junginger and A. Sell and O. Schubert and B. Mayer and D. Brida and M. Marangoni and G. Cerullo and A. Leitenstorfer and R. Huber}, 
journal = {Optics Letters},
number = {15},
pages = {2645--2647},
publisher = {OSA},
title = {Single-cycle multiterahertz transients with peak fields above 10 {MV}/cm},
volume = {35},
month = {Aug},
year = {2010},
url = {http://ol.osa.org/abstract.cfm?URI=ol-35-15-2645},
doi = {10.1364/OL.35.002645},
}
@article{LPOR:LPOR201000013,
author = {Cerullo, G. and Baltu{\v s}ka, A. and M{\"u}cke, O.D. and Vozzi, C.},
title = {Few-optical-cycle light pulses with passive carrier-envelope phase stabilization},
journal = {Laser \& Photonics Reviews},
volume = {5},
number = {3},
publisher = {WILEY-VCH Verlag},
issn = {1863-8899},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/lpor.201000013},
doi = {10.1002/lpor.201000013},
pages = {323--351},
year = {2011},
}
@inproceedings{Kanuparthy:2011:SED:2068816.2068860,
 author = {Partha Kanuparthy and Constantine Dovrolis},
 title = {ShaperProbe: end-to-end detection of ISP traffic shaping using active methods},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2011 ACM SIGCOMM conference on Internet measurement conference},
 series = {IMC '11},
 year = {2011},
 isbn = {978-1-4503-1013-0},
 location = {Berlin, Germany},
 pages = {473--482},
 numpages = {10},
 url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2068816.2068860},
 doi = {10.1145/2068816.2068860},
 acmid = {2068860},
 publisher = {ACM},
 address = {New York, NY, USA},
 keywords = {active probing, inference, traffic shaping},
}
@inproceedings{soule2004flow,
  title={Flow classification by histograms: or how to go on safari in the internet},
  author={Augustin Soule and Kav{\'e} Salamatia and Nina Taft and Richard Emilion and Konstantina Papagiannaki},
  booktitle={ACM SIGMETRICS Performance Evaluation Review},
  volume={32},
  number={1},
  pages={49--60},
  year={2004},
  organization={ACM}
}
@book{texbook,
  author = {Donald E. Knuth},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The {\TeX} Book},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional}
}

@book{latex:companion,
  author = {Frank Mittelbach and Michel Gossens
            and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle
            and Chris Rowley},
  year = {2004},
  title = {The {\LaTeX} Companion},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional},
  edition = {2}
}

@book{latex2e,
  author = {Leslie Lamport},
  year = {1994},
  title = {{\LaTeX}: a Document Preparation System},
  publisher = {Addison Wesley},
  address = {Massachusetts},
  edition = {2}
}

@article{knuth:1984,
  title={Literate Programming},
  author={Donald E. Knuth},
  journal={The Computer Journal},
  volume={27},
  number={2},
  pages={97--111},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}

@inproceedings{lesk:1977,
  title={Computer Typesetting of Technical Journals on {UNIX}},
  author={Michael Lesk and Brian Kernighan},
  booktitle={Proceedings of American Federation of
             Information Processing Societies: 1977
             National Computer Conference},
  pages={879--888},
  year={1977},
  address={Dallas, Texas}
}
@article{Khoe:1994:CML:2288694.2294265,
    author = {Khoe, G. -D.},
    title = {Coherent multicarrier lightwave technology for flexible capacity networks},
    journal = {Comm. Mag.},
    issue_date = {March 1994},
    volume = {32},
    number = {3},
    month = mar,
    year = {1994},
    issn = {0163-6804},
    pages = {22--33},
    numpages = {12},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/35.267438},
    doi = {10.1109/35.267438},
    acmid = {2294265},
    publisher = {IEEE Press},
    address = {Piscataway, NJ, USA},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\lipsum

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Example}\label{tab:example}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
    Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
    \hline
    X & Y & Z \\
    X & Y & Z \\
    X & Y & Z \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\appendix
\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}
\onecolumn
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Table with images},
  label = {tab:image},
]{
  hlines, vlines,
  colsep=3pt,
  colspec= {c *{3}{X[c,m]} },
  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
  rowsep = 3pt,
  rowhead = 1,
}

  No &   C1  &   C3  &   C4  \\
  1  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  2  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  3  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  4  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  5  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  6  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  7  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  8  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
\end{longtblr}
%
%
% twocolumn
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \section{reference}
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
    \bibliography{IEEEabrv,jobname.bib}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

However, this may result in the references not being balanced as intended. A single reference could be split between the two columns.This is different from, e.g., `\IEEEtriggeratref{}` which does not split individual references.

EDIT: sorry I edited the wrong post.

Comment: Would it be perfect if I manually add reference like `\IEEEtriggercmd{\columnbreak}\IEEEtriggeratref{n}`? I means there is no against the rules.

Comment: Yes, adding `\IEEEtriggercmd{\columnbreak}\IEEEtriggeratref{n}` seems to give the desired behavior.

Comment: I got the problem that it breaks another reference from left column of a page to the right column of the next page.

Comment: How can I use `multicol` but not balance the references? I still need to insert biography text and photo so I want to break column at some desired position instead of automatically balancing two columns now.

Comment: I succeed unbalce with `multicol*` but how can I force to move the citations to new column at some desired place like `\IEEEtriggeratref{n}`? Unfortunately this command doesn't work inside `multicol*`.

Answer (score 2):

Solution based on two regular tables.

[image]

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
  @article{Junginger:10,
  author = {F. Junginger and A. Sell and O. Schubert and B. Mayer and D. Brida and M. Marangoni and G. Cerullo and A. Leitenstorfer and R. Huber},
  journal = {Optics Letters},
  number = {15},
  pages = {2645--2647},
  publisher = {OSA},
  title = {Single-cycle multiterahertz transients with peak fields above 10 {MV}/cm},
  volume = {35},
  month = {Aug},
  year = {2010},
  url = {http://ol.osa.org/abstract.cfm?URI=ol-35-15-2645},
  doi = {10.1364/OL.35.002645},
  }
  @article{LPOR:LPOR201000013,
  author = {Cerullo, G. and Baltu{\v s}ka, A. and M{\"u}cke, O.D. and Vozzi, C.},
  title = {Few-optical-cycle light pulses with passive carrier-envelope phase stabilization},
  journal = {Laser \& Photonics Reviews},
  volume = {5},
  number = {3},
  publisher = {WILEY-VCH Verlag},
  issn = {1863-8899},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/lpor.201000013},
  doi = {10.1002/lpor.201000013},
  pages = {323--351},
  year = {2011},
  }
  @inproceedings{Kanuparthy:2011:SED:2068816.2068860,
  author = {Partha Kanuparthy and Constantine Dovrolis},
  title = {ShaperProbe: end-to-end detection of ISP traffic shaping using active methods},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2011 ACM SIGCOMM conference on Internet measurement conference},
  series = {IMC '11},
  year = {2011},
  isbn = {978-1-4503-1013-0},
  location = {Berlin, Germany},
  pages = {473--482},
  numpages = {10},
  url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2068816.2068860},
  doi = {10.1145/2068816.2068860},
  acmid = {2068860},
  publisher = {ACM},
  address = {New York, NY, USA},
  keywords = {active probing, inference, traffic shaping},
  }
  @inproceedings{soule2004flow,
  title={Flow classification by histograms: or how to go on safari in the internet},
  author={Augustin Soule and Kav{\'e} Salamatia and Nina Taft and Richard Emilion and Konstantina Papagiannaki},
  booktitle={ACM SIGMETRICS Performance Evaluation Review},
  volume={32},
  number={1},
  pages={49--60},
  year={2004},
  organization={ACM}
  }
  @book{texbook,
  author = {Donald E. Knuth},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The {\TeX} Book},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional}
  }

  @book{latex:companion,
  author = {Frank Mittelbach and Michel Gossens
  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle
  and Chris Rowley},
  year = {2004},
  title = {The {\LaTeX} Companion},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional},
  edition = {2}
  }

  @book{latex2e,
  author = {Leslie Lamport},
  year = {1994},
  title = {{\LaTeX}: a Document Preparation System},
  publisher = {Addison Wesley},
  address = {Massachusetts},
  edition = {2}
  }

  @article{knuth:1984,
  title={Literate Programming},
  author={Donald E. Knuth},
  journal={The Computer Journal},
  volume={27},
  number={2},
  pages={97--111},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
  }

  @inproceedings{lesk:1977,
  title={Computer Typesetting of Technical Journals on {UNIX}},
  author={Michael Lesk and Brian Kernighan},
  booktitle={Proceedings of American Federation of
  Information Processing Societies: 1977
  National Computer Conference},
  pages={879--888},
  year={1977},
  address={Dallas, Texas}
  }
  @article{Khoe:1994:CML:2288694.2294265,
  author = {Khoe, G. -D.},
  title = {Coherent multicarrier lightwave technology for flexible capacity networks},
  journal = {Comm. Mag.},
  issue_date = {March 1994},
  volume = {32},
  number = {3},
  month = mar,
  year = {1994},
  issn = {0163-6804},
  pages = {22--33},
  numpages = {12},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/35.267438},
  doi = {10.1109/35.267438},
  acmid = {2294265},
  publisher = {IEEE Press},
  address = {Piscataway, NJ, USA},
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}

\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}


\begin{document}
\lipsum

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Example}\label{tab:example}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
    Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
    \hline
    X & Y & Z \\
    X & Y & Z \\
    X & Y & Z \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\appendix
\raggedbottom

\begin{table*}
  \caption{Table with images}\label{tab:image}
  \begin{tblr}{
      hlines, vlines,
      colsep=3pt,
      colspec= {c *{3}{X[c,m]} },
      row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
      rowsep = 3pt,
    }
    No &   C1  &   C3  &   C4  \\
    1  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
    2  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
    3  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
    4  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
    5  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}
  \end{tblr}
\end{table*}
\begin{table*}
  \caption{Table with images (Continued)}\label{tab:image-cont}
  \begin{tblr}{
    hlines, vlines,
    colsep=3pt,
    colspec= {c *{3}{X[c,m]} },
    row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    rowsep = 3pt,
  }
    No &   C1  &   C3  &   C4  \\
    6  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
    7  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
    8  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  \end{tblr}
\end{table*}

\pagebreak
%\IEEEtriggercmd{\columnbreak}\IEEEtriggeratref{7}
\section{reference}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,jobname.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: in my real article, the second table is placed vertically in the middle of a page and the bibliography is put in the next page.  Is there any possible reason for this? I copied your table* and bibliography and then change the real text so I don't think I missed anything in the section.

Comment: Somehow `\include{appendix}` caused this problem. Im I used `\include` wrong?

Comment: This method also has the problem of single citation splits across two columns and two pages. I don't know if this is normal though. I checked many papers from IEEE and didn't see this issue.

Comment: I see. You should use `\input{}`, instead. `\nclude` is meant to add `\chapter`s or `\part`s, starts a new page, and is more than just inserting a code. It creates its own *.aux files. [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Management_in_a_large_project) has a good info on that.

Comment: As to the citation problem, it sounds like a quite common issue because it's in the "XIV. LAST PAGE COLUMN EQUALIZATION"  in the [document](https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) by Michael Shell , a maintainer of this document class.

Comment: Yeah, `\input` works. 
What if the split happens multiple times? Can I use `\IEEEtriggeratref{}` in multiple places?

Comment: Hmm, Michael Shell wrote _`\IEEEtriggeratref{10}`_ [added] _before the bibliography will insert a page break just before reference number ten_. It seems to me you could use it multiple times and issue multiple page breaks--my guess.

Comment: I tried to put the two commands in consecutive `\IEEEtriggeratref{8}
\IEEEtriggeratref{15}` and only the last one is effective.

Comment: This might need a new question, then.

Comment: Can be 'Continued on next page' added at the end of the first table like in the original long table. It looks very nice so want to keep it.

Comment: Append `\SetCell[c=<n>]{halign=r} {\scfamily ....}` as the last row, where `<n>` is a no. of columns to merge and `....` is whatever must appear at the bottom.

Comment: I got some error. Is this correct? How can I remove the boundaries on the last row of the text?
https://ibb.co/j67vdgy

Comment: I don't use vertical lines so I removed `vlines` but there is still one horizontal line below `coninuted on next page` that I want to remove.

Comment: I share your project on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/hsvyzwdscqrf). It's working there. And, yes you would need to work out horizontal and vertical lines. Refer to [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) documentation.

Comment: Thanks, sorry to ask one more question if it's easy to solve or should I ask in a new post. In my real document, these two tables is splited and citations are inserted between them. I tried minipage but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Well, I assume LaTeX creates a separate "float page" for the big table and places it on the next empty page. This is independent of the rest of the document. The small table is a regular float placed at the top of the next available page with text. Therefore, when your text splits pages, the big table interferes. I can't think of a solution. I guess you would tru to move text around or force it with `clearpage` but very likely end up with a big chunk of white space.

Comment: I solved it with `\FloatBarrier`. Part of the problem was due to I made the first table 4 rows so there are some space left for text to added between them. So I change it to 5 rows also use `\FloatBarrier` to force the bibliography to the last page.

Comment: I see, of course `\FloatBarrier`! I didn't think of it. I am glad it's working for you.